# What does f1 , head -1 , tail -1 mean in : cut -f1 -d"," file_name | sort -n | head -1?

Tags: bash

I found it in a thread on sorting , am not getting what does 1 imply in f1 and what is head or tail in the given code ?

```
    cut -f1 -d"," file_name | sort -n | head -1
```

Comment: Run `man cut`, `man head` and `man tail`.

Comment: `tail` isn't even in the code.

Answer (score 0):

The `head` command is used to read the beginning of a file and discard the rest.

The `tail` command is used to discard the beginning of a file and read the rest.

In both cases, "file" means either a an actual (special or regular) file in the directory tree, or the input fed to standard in, as when the command is part of a pipe, redirection, or process substitution.

In both cases, options control how many lines are kept/discarded.  Please read the manual of these utilities for more details.